# Why doesn't trackpad work in Preview or TextEdit?

Tags: trackpad

I open a PDF document.  It's a document I've created.  I have my trackpad set on "tap to click" from the trackpad system preferences.  Right now the tap with one finger doesn't work when I have the PDF document open. Physically clicking with the trackpad doesn't work.  The two-finger tap for a right click works.  Physically clicking in the area of the trackpad that signifies a right click works.  No left click works.  This is true for all PDFs I open.  This is true for any file I open with TextEdit.  Everything works fine in Chrome, Safari, Mathematica, etc.

Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated.  I have tried this with a mouse since I don't have a mouse.  I'm using a Macbook Air 11" late 2011 model running Lion.

Comment: I attached a mouse and the behavior persists.

Comment: Can you please clarify what you mean by "doesn't work" with respect to the one finger click? Especially given that each of the clicking methods you describe can or does do something different by default (e.g., two-finger clicking on a page in Preview "works" by bringing up a contextual menu)

Comment: Two finger clicking works.  This corresponds to right clicking with a mouse.  The single tap doesn't work.  This corresponds to left clicking on a mouse.  Using a mouse gives the same behavior.  Left clicking doesn't do anything.  Can't highlight, can't click to close or do anything else.  Physicall clicking the trackpad gives the same behavior.  Right click works and left clicking doesn't do anything.